# How to create a single jquery plugin function that is callable both on jQuery instances and the jQuery object itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created JQuery plugin like this:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(className)
{
    if(className) {
        // create new instance of className and return it
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    }
};
```

When I use it like this: `$("div").myPlugin();` it works fine.

Buy when I use `$.myPlugin("TestClass")` it does not work.
note: TestClass exist.

Comment: because it is not a static function, you can write `$.myMethod = function()
{
    alert("test");
}` then `$.myMethod()`

Comment: If you've written your plugin as code that expects to operate on a jQuery object, what is it that you expect `$.myplugin` to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `$.customFunction` to be set, you need to assign a value to it:

```
$.customFunction = function () {
    alert('this works!');
};
```

---

given your update, you should use two separate functions:

```
$.myPlugin = function (classname) {
    //create new instance of className and return it
}

$.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    this.css('background-color', 'red');
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to mix them?

Comment: @Eeliya, why would you want to?

Comment: I have namespace for my plugins like $("div").namespace().myPlugin() but some function that create an element so I want something like  $.namespace("CreateFileChooser").myPlugin();

Comment: @Eeliya, please update your question to reflect your *actual* problem. If you skip important details like the fact that you've got an intermediary function `.namespace()` which could return an unknown type, it's impossible for anyone to give you accurate advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `extend` function:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myFunction: function(){
        alert("Hi!");
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is there difference between using extend and using custom function name?

Comment: If you're going to suggest the `extend` function, I recommend using [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) over [`jQuery.fn.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/).

Answer (score -2):

For a simple plugin like that (that has no notion of `this`), you might want something like

```
$.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin = function()
{
    alert("test");
};
```

`$.fn` is the prototype, so you're giving every jQuery instance that function (method, really).

Direct assignment to `$` will make it a static function on the global jQuery object.

---

To update my answer to your updated question, here's one way to do what I think you want to do (keep it all in one function? -- please note: I am trying to read your mind here ;):

```
$.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin = function(className) {
    var isInstance = (this instanceof $); // true if invoked on an instance
    if (className) { // whenever a className is given
        className = '.' + className; // turn it into a selector (assumes only one class)
        return isInstance ? $(className, this) : $(className); // returns jQuery object
    } else if (isInstance) { // when invoked on an instance
        return this.css("background-color","red"); // sets color and returns this
    }
};
```

If you want two completely different behaviors based on how the plugin is called, however, it is clearer and more maintainable to write them as two separate functions:

```
// returns jQuery object containing element(s) that have a given className
$.myPlugin = function(className) {
    // turn className into selector (assumes only one class name is given)
    var selector = className ? ('.' + className) : '';

    return $(selector);

};

// sets color and returns this
$.fn.myOtherPlugin = function() {
    return this.css('background-color', 'red');
};
```

You may additionally want to give the plugins different names that are indicative of their respective functions (hence `myOtherPlugin`).

Comment: this is bad advice because the way `$('div').myPlugin()` should execute is significantly different from how `$.myPlugin()` should execute.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I wouldn't say this is entirely a bad idea.  It isn't a common idea, but there could be some cases where you have a static method that you want to work on either just `$` or on an existing jQuery object.

Comment: @jfriend00, it's certainly *possible* to write a function that can correctly handle the difference between acting on the `jQuery` function and an instance created from the `jQuery` function, but writing the code to support this behavior would involve unnecessary checks that could be avoided simply by writing two different functions.

Comment: @zzzzBov - you don't seem to follow that you could have a `static` function (one that does use `this` at all) that you find it syntactically convenient to be able to use as either a method of `$` or as a method on an existing jQuery object.  Logging as an example comes to mind.

Comment: @jfriend00, I fully understand that it's possible to write code that will execute irrespective of context, however for many of those cases I don't feel that it's worth polluting the jQuery namespace at all. I've found that logging is typically better handled separately from jQuery.

Comment: @zzzzBov, just wanted to verify what you think the user is asking. I'm not sure your criticisms apply to this question (and my updated answer may make this more clear).

Comment: @Noyo, I believe that OP may have been asking an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My criticisms of this answer has always been on `$.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin = function () {...` being a bad recommendation, and, as this answer still contains that suggestion, my downvote remains.

Comment: @zzzzBov, that said, if it was an XY Problem, wouldn't you say that the utility of my recommendation really depends on X? I'm not arguing that it's a bad recommendation _in the general case_, but if OP's X had for whatever reason required the use of a single function (as was implied by the actual question), what is wrong with demonstrating one way in which this is possible, caveats included? I'm genuinely curious, as it sounds like we just had two different but valid interpretations of X, and that your criticisms don't consider other valid use cases. In any case, I've expanded my response.